# Bootstrap make part of the image clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Fairly new to this. At the moment I have an image and a button in one of the containers in my front page. I'm trying to embed that button into that image. Should I

1. make part of that image clickable, and let that trigger a function?
2. or force that button to float on certain position of that picture?

Or is there another way that I should follow? and how do I implement this? Many thanks!

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center"> 
        <img src="../img/background.png" class="rounded" alt="">
        <button  type="button" id="s"  class="btn" >Make payment</button> //I'm trying to have this button float on that image above
</div>
```

Comment: You'd probably want to go with option 2, as it would be far easier. You can achieve that with relative positioning, but you'd need to provide an image of exactly what you want the output to look like in order for us to provide exact code showing how to do it.

Comment: You might also consider an image map. There are online generators that make them really easy to make.

Comment: I also have an input field on that page.. That's where that button grabs the value from. I could still achieve this with the second option?

Comment: since the image is a background image, why not just remove the `img` tag all together and make it the `background-image` for the `div`? That way you have the option using non-absolute positioning methods on the button and/or div like padding and margin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute` to make it float on the image. look at this

https://jsfiddle.net/5ueau24b/1/

```css
#s
{
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: -200px;
   margin-top: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center"> 
        <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/images_1_05GM1zY.jpg" class="rounded" alt="">
        <button  type="button" id="s"  class="btn" >Make payment</button> //I'm trying to have this button float on that image above
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using imagemap of html. (map tag in specific)